# CollectionView Cells Need Two Taps Because of GestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I have added GestureRecognizer for hide keyboard when user click to anywhere in view without textview. Its working well but CollectionView Cells need two tap for work, when I delete GestureRecognizer its working well but I need both of them. I have searched this in couple hours and tried so many solutions but anything is not worked.

GestureRecognizer for hide keyboard when user click to anywhere in view without textview;

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

@objc func handleTap() {

  textBody.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method:

```
public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true) // or textBody.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, this solution worked. you saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

To recognize both gestures simultaneously use below code by removing `cancelsTouchesInView` line. You may need to add another tap gesture for your `collectionView` according to your need. Or use `scrollViewDidScroll` event of `collectionView` to hide the keyboard.

```
   //tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
   tapRecognizer.delegate = self
   view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)


extension MyViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have solved this problem thanks to j.Doe`s answer :) Its working well now